# Java G1: Monitoring for memory leaks in production

Tags: java, garbage-collection, g1gc

For years, we've been running Java services with modest heap sizes using `+UseParallelOldGC`. Now, we're starting to roll out a new service using a larger heap and the G1 collector. This is going pretty well.

For our services that use `+UseParallelOldGC`, we monitor for memory leaks by looking at the old generation size after collection and alerting on a threshold. This works quite well, and in fact saved our bacon just two weeks ago.

Specifically, for `+UseParallelOldGC`, we do the following:

- `ManagementFactory.getMemoryPoolMXBeans()`
- Search for the `MemoryPoolMXBean` result with the name ending in `"Old Gen"`
- Compare `getCollectionUsage().getUsed()` (if available) with `getMax()`

Unfortunately, it seems like G1 no longer has a concept of `getCollectionUsage()`.

Fundamentally, though, we'd like to monitor the G1 heap size following the last mixed collection it chooses to do in a mixed cycle, or something similar.

For example, outside the VM I would be happy with an awk script that merely found the last `'(mixed)'` was that's followed by a `'(young)'` and look what the final heap size was (e.g., `'1540.0M' 'Heap: 3694.5M(9216.0M)->1540.0M(9216.0M)'`)

Is there any way to do this inside the Java VM?

Comment: this should provide similar information: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32509813/1362755

Answer (score 2):

Yes, JVM gives you enough tools to retrieve such information for G1. For instance, you could use something like this class that prints all the details about garbage collections (just call `MemoryUtil.startGCMonitor()`):

```
public class MemoryUtil {

    private static final Set<String> heapRegions;

    static {
        heapRegions = ManagementFactory.getMemoryPoolMXBeans().stream()
                .filter(b -> b.getType() == MemoryType.HEAP)
                .map(MemoryPoolMXBean::getName)
                .collect(Collectors.toSet());
    }

    private static NotificationListener gcHandler = (notification, handback) -> {
        if (notification.getType().equals(GarbageCollectionNotificationInfo.GARBAGE_COLLECTION_NOTIFICATION)) {
            GarbageCollectionNotificationInfo gcInfo = GarbageCollectionNotificationInfo.from((CompositeData) notification.getUserData());
            Map<String, MemoryUsage> memBefore = gcInfo.getGcInfo().getMemoryUsageBeforeGc();
            Map<String, MemoryUsage> memAfter = gcInfo.getGcInfo().getMemoryUsageAfterGc();
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(250);
            sb.append("[").append(gcInfo.getGcAction()).append(" / ").append(gcInfo.getGcCause())
                    .append(" / ").append(gcInfo.getGcName()).append(" / (");
            appendMemUsage(sb, memBefore);
            sb.append(") -> (");
            appendMemUsage(sb, memAfter);
            sb.append("), ").append(gcInfo.getGcInfo().getDuration()).append(" ms]");
            System.out.println(sb.toString());
        }
    };

    public static void startGCMonitor() {
        for(GarbageCollectorMXBean mBean: ManagementFactory.getGarbageCollectorMXBeans()) {
            ((NotificationEmitter) mBean).addNotificationListener(gcHandler, null, null);
        }
    }

    public static void stopGCMonitor() {
        for(GarbageCollectorMXBean mBean: ManagementFactory.getGarbageCollectorMXBeans()) {
            try {
                ((NotificationEmitter) mBean).removeNotificationListener(gcHandler);
            } catch(ListenerNotFoundException e) {
                // Do nothing
            }
        }
    }

    private static void appendMemUsage(StringBuilder sb, Map<String, MemoryUsage> memUsage) {
        memUsage.entrySet().forEach((entry) -> {
            if (heapRegions.contains(entry.getKey())) {
                sb.append(entry.getKey()).append(" used=").append(entry.getValue().getUsed() >> 10).append("K; ");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

In this code, `gcInfo.getGcAction()` gives you enough information to separate minor collections from major/mixed ones.

But there's an important caveat to using your approach (with a threshold) to G1. A single mixed collection in G1 usually affects only several old gen regions - many enough to free sufficient amount of memory but not too many in order to keep the GC pause low. So, after a mixed collection in G1 you cannot be sure that all your garbage has gone. As a result, you need to find more sophisticated strategy to detect memory leaks (maybe based on collections frequency, gathering statistics from several collections, etc.)